# SQL User vs AAD for Azure SQL Managed instance

Tags: sql-server, azure

It appears the app response is much slower when it uses the AAD  account to access the Managed instance compared to using a SQL user (SQL Auth).

Can anyone please shed some light on whether this is expected behaviour? or we need to check if there is some issue with the AAD Domain services.

I believe there will be a bit of latency but should not be noticable.

Also how exactly the Authentication works in case of AAD?

Comment: [Factors influencing the performance of Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-performance-factors) and [Configure and manage Azure Active Directory authentication with SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) might help.

Comment: Thanks. already went through .still searching for something that would narrow down how much is the expected latency during AAD auth.